# Sorting Numpy Array of two different types

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, data-structures

I mainly code in C++ and I'm trying to figure out how to sort this data structure that I've managed to create. Please find the code following:

```
dtype = [('dist',float) , ('type',int)]
arr = np.zeros((200,2), dtype = dtype)
i = 0
for current_image in all_images:
    arr[i][0] = distance(current_image, new_image)
    if current_image[576] == 1:
        arr[i][1] = 1
    else:
        arr[i][1] = 0
    i = i + 1
```

I wanted to create a 200 by 2 array of floats in the first column and ints in the second. I'm not particularly sure how to sort all 200 elements based on the dist value from smallest to largest. Also my data structure looks strange, something like this:

```
[[( 9.47168802,  9) ( 0.        ,  0)]
[( 6.95162905,  6) ( 1.        ,  1)]
[( 8.72382552,  8) ( 0.        ,  0)]
[( 8.9333134 ,  8) ( 1.        ,  1)]]
```

Comment: You say your data structure looks strange.  It looks OK to me.   What's strange about it?  What did you expect it to look like?

Comment: I thought it would look more like:

[[( 9.47168802,  0)]
[( 6.95162905,  1)]
[( 8.72382552,  0)]
[(8.9333134, 1)]]
But I can see it seems to store both the float and int version of both dist and type, just not what I expected

Comment: Is the surprise perhaps because you gave it the shape `(200,2)` and not just `200`?  Did you think you needed to make it 200x2 to hold 200 pairs?  Because as the code is written, it holds 400 pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort it simply:

```
arr.sort(axis=0)
```

You could also explicitly mention the sort key, though this is optional in your case because it is the first field anyway:

```
arr.sort(axis=0, order='dist')
```

Or to make a copy instead of sorting in-place:

```
np.sort(arr, axis=1, order='dist')
```

Comment: This seems to return None?

Comment: Yes, it returns None.  It sorts `arr` in place.  If you prefer, try `np.sort(arr)` instead, which makes a copy and returns it.

Comment: Okay, I understand. However this seems to flip my type and dist

[[( 0.        ,  0) ( 9.47168802,  9)]
 [( 1.        ,  1) ( 6.95162905,  6)]
 [( 0.        ,  0) ( 8.72382552,  8)]
 [( 1.        ,  1) ( 8.9333134 ,  8)]
 [( 0.        ,  0) ( 6.49717225,  6)]]

When I expected it to sort all rows based on the dist value

Comment: @JarredMcEvoy: You can try adding `axis=0` or `axis=1` to control the sort axis.  See the docs.

Comment: Thanks, it sorted properly once I gave it the shape 200 as you commented on my question!